# How to designate a local repository as a remote for another local repository?

Tags: git, git-push, git-clone, git-remote, git-fetch

In order to better understand how Git works, I'd like to inspect the changes that a remote repository undergoes as it interacts with a local repository (via fetch, push, etc.).

1. Suppose I have two Git repositories, A and B, in my local file system. Is it possible to designate A as a remote repository with respect to B, so that, for instance all `push` commands performed in B will be pushed to A?
2. Is it possible to clone a new local repository C from A using the `clone` command?

Comment: why you want to create a host a repo local , when it can be done easily using the github without any cost.

Comment: @AmitK: How can I inspect, for instance, the value of HEAD on the remote repository when it is hosted on GitHub?

Comment: @AmitK the answer to your question is described in the first sentence of the OP's question: *"In order to better understand how Git works"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both your questions is: Yes!

Use the Git commands as usual and pass the full or the relative path of the other repository as argument `<repository>`.

For example, use:

```
git clone ../repoA repoB
```

to clone the repository `../repoA` into the sub-directory `repoB` of the current directory.

Read more about the [ways to specify an URL](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#URLS) in Git commands that require an URL of a remote repository.

Answer (score 2):

All Git repositories are *peers*, as far as Git itself is concerned.  Furthermore, any repository is at least logically entirely self-contained (there are some tricky things you can do with "alternate object locations" that makes them *physically* interdependent, but let's ignore that for now).

> Suppose I have two Git repositories, A and B, in my local file system. Is it possible to designate A as a remote repository with respect to B, so that, for instance all push commands performed in B will be pushed to A?

Back this up for a moment and let's look at the definition of *remote*.  The term is somewhat overloaded (we can talk about a "remote peer" or "a Git at some remote host", for instance), but each Git repository defines, through its own local configuration file (`git config`), some number—possibly zero—of *remotes*.

A remote is just a name, like `origin` or, in our case, `A`.  The name becomes part of slightly longer names that are used as key/value pairs: `remote.A.key1` = `some-value`, `remote.A.key2` = `another value`, and so on.

So, in repository B, we can define a remote named `A`, setting some of these key/value pairs.  At least one key/value pair is required (so that the `[remote "A"]` section gets created), and a `url` setting is appropriate here:

```
cd B
git config remote.A.url <some url here>
```

Repo `B` now has a remote named `A`.  The URL can be just a simple path, or `ssh://host.name/path/to/repo.git`, or something starting with `git://` or `http://` or `https://` or `file://`.

The URL needs to reach a Git that can read and/or write the other repository.  If the URL is a local file system path, your own Git plays both roles, but at least logically, it *pretends* to talk to a separate Git that represents the other repository.

A second `remote.A` entry is pretty important if `B` will ever run `git fetch` to *read* from `A`.  This will supply the default refspec, which would generally be:

```
git config --add remote.A.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/A/*'
```

Note that there may be multiple `fetch` refspecs defined this way (which is a reason to use `--add` here).  While you are in repository `B`, if you now run either `git fetch` *or* `git push` and use the name `A` as the remote, your Git will call up another Git that will send objects from `A` (if you are fetching) or receive objects destined for `A` (if you are pushing).

Note that the default *fetch* refspec or refspecs comes from `git config --get-all remote.A.url`, but the default *push* refspec or refspecs are more complicated (depend on `push.default`, and/or if they are set, `remote.A.push` and `remote.A.mirror` settings).

There is also an optional `remote.A.pushurl` setting.  If this is set, `git push A` connects not to the `remote.A.url` address, but rather to the `remote.A.pushurl` address.

(There is also `remote.pushDefault`: if you run `git push` with no *remote* specified, the `remote.pushDefault` overrides the current branch's `branch.branch.remote` setting, but not its `branch.branch.pushRemote` setting.  This is all pretty crazy complicated and the only way to keep track is to consult [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).)

Note that you don't *have* to use a named remote here at all!  You can:

```
git fetch <url> <refspec>
```

and:

```
git push <url> <refspec>
```

The benefit to using a named remote like `A` is that you gain all these configuration entries that do fancy things for you, such as remember complicated URLs and complicated default refspecs.  Moreover, this enables you to do:

```
git config branch.evil.remote A
git config branch.zorg.remote A
```

which means that whenever you are on branches `evil` or `zorg`, your Git should connect, by default, to remote `A`.  Combine this with a `url` setting and a default `fetch` setting to set up remote-tracking branches in the `refs/remotes/A/` name-space, and you get a convenient way to talk to the remote Git, whether it is "very remote" (on another machine entirely) or "not at all remote" (on your own machine)—though the fancy remote-tracking branch stuff is obviously much less important for a not-at-all-remote remote.

(Configuring the `branch.name.remote` setting is half of the job of configuring the *upstream* for that branch.  The other half is done by configuring `branch.name.merge`.  Using `git branch --set-upstream-to=A/zorg`, as you might do on your branch `zorg`, sets both at once.)

> Is it possible to clone a new local repository C from A using the clone command?

Yes: the syntax for `git clone` is `git clone [ options ] url [ directory ]`.  The URL can, as before, just be a simple path name.  If it is, this enables the `--local` option by default.

Cloning a repository automatically creates a remote in the new Git repository.  This remote is named `origin` by default, and has two default settings:

```
remote.origin.url = <url>
remote.origin.fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

which are of course the recommended settings for any remote.  Note that the right hand side of the refspec value of the `fetch` setting embeds the name of the remote in it: here it's `origin`, while for `remote.A.fetch` it was `A`.

> ... I'd like to inspect the changes that a remote repository undergoes as it interacts with a local repository (via fetch, push, etc.).

There really is no "etc": fetch and push are it.  You can run `git ls-remote` and `git remote show`, and those two can connect one Git to another, but they do not *interact* at that point: these just obtain public references and either print them out (`git ls-remote`) or compare them to settings in your local repository (`git remote show`).

The "obtain public references" step is the first—well, second, perhaps—step in `git fetch` and `git push` as well, since your Git (you are the one running or push) wants to decide *what to fetch* or *what to push*, and these tend to require knowing what references exist in the other Git.  (Push seems like it might not care what "they" have, but it does for `matching` and for `simple`, at least.  The *first* step, if you want to call this the second step, is establishing common protocol capabilities, which is something all the "smart" transports do, since the protocol has evolved somewhat over time.)